# different openssl responses in different shells

Tags: bash, openssl, sh

The following works in bash (/bin/bash):

Code:

```
echo "U2FsdGVkX198UexvhHEtfC7iLbT3awAfla77fvSjZQJ0LC4GmDMeLOghPWXpyy6e" | openssl aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass file:<( echo -n "toy" )
Fri Sep 15 15:20:01 PDT 2017
```

But fails when run in sh (/bin/sh):

Code:

```
echo "U2FsdGVkX198UexvhHEtfC7iLbT3awAfla77fvSjZQJ0LC4GmDMeLOghPWXpyy6e" | openssl aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass file:<( echo -n "toy" )
sh: 15: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

is there a way around this?

As you can see here, i'm using a named pipe for the password and id like to continue doing that. I just need this (or a very close variation of it) to work in /bin/sh.

OS: All Unix flavors.

Comment: I assume that `sh` does not know `<(...)`.

Comment: You aren't using a named pipe; you are using process substitution, which is not supported when `bash` runs as `/bin/sh`. (The fact that process substitution may be implemented as a named pipe isn't relevant.)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a named pipe explicitly:

```
mkfifo passwd
printf '%s' "toy" > passwd &
echo "U2FsdGVkX198UexvhHEtfC7iLbT3awAfla77fvSjZQJ0LC4GmDMeLOghPWXpyy6e" | 
  openssl aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass file:passwd
rm passwd
```

Comment: but this can be intercepted by a hacker, right?  i want to supply the passwd in one run.  I dont want to have to create any external file that needs to be removed.

Comment: A process substitution is just `bash` syntax for either a named pipe or an entry under `/dev/fd`, depending on what the underlying platform supports.

Comment: The fact that the password is stored in clear text in a shell script is a much bigger security risk than how the process substitution is implemented, though.

Comment: Note that `echo -n` will do different things under different shells (and in different modes and...). `printf '%s'` (as used in this answer) is really the right way to do this.